# Java JDBC vs JPA for database application

Tags: java, design-patterns, jpa, jdbc

I'd like to preface that I'm somewhat of a novice looking for advice as I'm trying to build good habits.

The application I'm developing right now is a heavily integrated database application. As I develop and explore and implement the requirements for each of my entities, I'm finding that my classes are just exploding with code to run queries in different ways on each of the entities.

While it might not be a bad thing right now, in terms of maintenance, I foresee my application being a nightmare to debug and update.

Do any JDBC experts out there have any suggestions for design patters that would help slim down the boiler-plate type code for handling all of these queries? Or should I stray from that completely and use JPA?

I've tried to implement JPA in the past, but have had trouble with complex entity relationships. Should I just read a JPA book and go from there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JPA can be a good long-term solution. But if you prefer to stay closer to plain SQL, you can consider other options like [Spring Framework's JDBC support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html).

Note that, you don't need to use other spring framework components link DI, MVC etc to be able to use Spring JDBC. It is quiet easy to use without other parts spring framework. 
When using spring jdbc, you **don't** need to do following tasks in your code:

1. Open the connection.
2. Prepare and execute the statement.
3. Set up the loop to iterate through the results (if any).
4. Process any exception.
5. Handle transactions.
6. Close the connection, statement and resultset.

What you need to do is:

1. Define connection parameters. (once)
2. Specify the SQL statement. (for each query)
3. Declare parameters and provide parameter values (when using prepared statements)
4. Do the work for each iteration. (spring do the resultset traversal, you only need to provide logic for acting on a single row)

Another benefit of spring-jdbc is that it replaces JDBC checked exceptions with unchecked exceptions.

Comment: So I am confused, why are UNchecked exceptions better than checked exceptions?

Comment: @Dennis: See [the exceptions debate](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html)  for a detailed look at pros and cons of checked exceptions vs. unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

Whatever solution you DO use, be it straight JDBC or JPA, be sure to break your code up into pieces that can be easily swapped out when the time comes to change technologies.

The downside with JDBC is that you may end up with implementation specific code (Oracle, MS, MySQL, etc.)  This can be a real pain to migrate away from if you decide to change things down the road.

I ended up studying up on Hibernate, and the book [Harnessing Hibernate](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517724) got me quite a ways into doing that kind of development (and also brought Spring and Maven along for the ride, in ways that slowly built on top of one another.)

What you should end up with, regardless of approach, are:

- DAO objects -- these Data Access Objects will do your CRUD operations (create, update, and delete) and should be database agnostic.
- Model objects -- these should represent your data, and will probably look a lot like Java representations of a single row in a database table.  DAO classes will return these, or lists of these.

Harnessing Hibernate describes a pattern in later chapters (after it has thrown Spring at you) where you'll use essentially two layers of DAO classes.  The highest level DAO class will instantiate (or allow to be injected) an implementation specific DAO class.

So, let's pretend you have an EMPLOYEE database table.  So you create a model object called Employee that holds all the data a row in the EMPLOYEE table holds.  Now you create a DAO class called EmployeeDAO that implements the following:

```
EmployeeDAO.createEmployee(Employee emp)
EmployeeDAO.updateEmployee(Employee emp)
EmployeeDAO.deleteEmployee(Employee emp)
```

Your initial thinking would be to put your JDBC calls there.  But don't do it.  Instead, you now write another DAO for Employee, and this one will implement all your JDBC calls.  (Assuming you go JDBC):

```
EmployeeJdbcDAO.create(Employee emp)
EmployeeJdbcDAO.update(Employee emp)
EmployeeJdbcDAO.delete(Employee emp)
```

Now the methods in EmployeeDAO?  They simply instantiate EmployeeJdbcDAO, and call the appropriate method.  When it comes time down the road to switch to Oracle with Hibernate, you create a new DAO class called something like EmployeeOrHibDAO, write Hibernate and Oracle specific code there, and then instead of calling EmployeeJdbcDAO in EmployeeDAO, you instantiate EmployeeOrHibDAO instead.  (And with Spring, you don't even change the code.  You just change your Spring DI configuration.)

Comment: -1: While great in theory, JDBC DAOs and Hibernate/JPA DAOs aren't interchangeable. The two technologies are way too far apart to be drop-in replacements for each other.

Comment: While I personally wouldn't bother with a JDBC DAO, I don't see why they couldn't be accommodated.

Comment: A JDBC DAO is fine. My point is that they're completely non-interchangeable with an ORM DAO because the concepts are completely differen

Comment: I think you should read the same book I did before down-voting my proposal then, because you can absolutely write a JDBC DAO that could be replaced with a Hibernate (or other ORM) DAO.  If JDBC is the route taken, then this proposal would limit the cohesiveness of the JDBC code, making it much easier to move to another solution down the road.  Which is the key point of the pattern.  All you would have to do is write a new DAO and use Spring to inject it into the app.

Comment: What's the book? [Here's](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html) the DAO pattern in its original incarnation for reference.

Comment: It's called Harnessing Hibernate.  It's linked to in the original post.

Comment: Thanks for the link to a description of the pattern.  And from that, here's a description of the DAO component:  "The DataAccessObject is the primary object of this pattern. The DataAccessObject abstracts the underlying data access implementation for the BusinessObject to enable transparent access to the data source. The BusinessObject also delegates data load and store operations to the DataAccessObject."  Where in this document does it say it can't abstract a JDBC implementation?  In fact, it DOES go so far as to say that it doesn't even have to be a RDMS implementation.

Comment: Haven't read that book, so I can't comment on it. Just think about this: how would you implement a clear(), evict(), flush(), or merge() in a JDBC DAO? Those are all operations common to the current generation of ORMs. What about cascading persistence operations? Would you emulate that in a JDBC DAO?

Comment: We're not talking about writing an ORM.  We're talking about writing a DAO to abstract basic CRUD operations.  Create, Read, Update, and Delete.  All of those methods (called out in the DAO pattern you pointed me at) can be easily implemented using an ORM like Hibernate, or JDBC.  I suspect most applications (certainly the ones I've worked on) can get by without the methods you list.  I further speculate that the original question concerned itself with a beginning application, and nothing quite as I dunno, advanced as what you're apparently talking about.

Comment: ONe thing I like about the Java community . . . they promote technological solutions vs marketspeak. LIke Unices (plural Unix), which use 'everything is a file' resource access and kernel with layered services and applications around the kernel. (CR) So to my way of thinking, the more recent promotion of JPA for database access is a STANDARDIZED, best practices encapsulating abstraction and the direction new development should go. It's technologically superior and lower maintenance.

Comment: +1 to Spring/Hibernate, too steep a learning curve for the OPs original intended use, but for more complex implementations I believe it is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Not a *real* answer but, i do think it's important to throw in a couple more options in the mix that may help you find a good middle ground.  I suggest this because a JPA implementation on a existing database with lots of complexity and queries can be a little troublesome for a someone without a fair share of battle scars.  Consider the following but do the research and build some tracer bullet apps;

1. [Spring JDBCTemplate and DAO Pattern](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html) Love this for solutions where JPA\Hibernate just don't make sense.
2. [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/)  Again, another nice middle ground with a little more control over the SQL

Comment: These are all great answers! I'm a little curious about your #1 point though: do you have a quick, generalized example of where JPA/Hibernate would not make sense?

Comment: Simple applications that don't need the JPA baggage or legacy databases that i'll spend more time fitting into JPA than just building out some DAOs.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to build good habits I would read [Code Complete 2](http://www.cc2e.com/) by Steve McConnell.

Comment: Code Complete 2 has a lot of great stuff but I don't think it really applies to the specifics of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't discard an [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) as an option. That doesn't have to be an EJB entity approach. The pattern is worth mentioning IMHO